# pyspark filtering result from window function

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I used this command

```
df = df.groupBy("item_name", window("ts_utc","10 minutes").alias("ts_utc")).agg(F.min(df.item_value).alias("min"),F.max(df.item_value).alias("max"),F.avg(df.item_value).alias("avg"),F.sum(df.item_value).alias("sum"))
```

to get the min,max,avg,sum values for each item based on timestamp with 10min interval.

the output I want for ts_utc column(Timestamp) is like

```
2020-07-04T11:20:00.000+0000
2020-07-04T11:30:00.000+0000
2020-07-04T11:40:00.000+0000
2020-07-04T11:50:00.000+0000
```

but the result I get from the above command is

```
{"start": "2020-07-04T11:20:00.000+0000","end": "2020-07-04T11:30:00.000+0000"}
{"start": "2020-07-04T11:30:00.000+0000","end": "2020-07-04T11:40:00.000+0000"}
{"start": "2020-07-04T11:40:00.000+0000","end": "2020-07-04T11:50:00.000+0000"}
{"start": "2020-07-04T11:50:00.000+0000","end": "2020-07-04T12:00:00.000+0000"}
```

How could I only get the start time from the window function and not in Json format.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get only the `start` part of the window.

```
df = df.withCoulumn('ts_utc', F.col('ts_utc.start'))
```